# Overriding method call operator or some other way to catch method name resolution errors

Tags: oop, raku, dispatch

I am trying to write an example for the [`X::NYI`](https://docs.raku.org/type/X::NYI) class as a response to [this issue](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/2052). I have come up with something like this:

```
class Nothing {
    sub postfix:<.&>( $sub, **@args) {
        die X::NYI.new( feature => $sub,
                        did-you-mean => "nothing",
                        workaround => "Implement it yourself" );
    }
}

my $let's-see = Nothing.newish;
```

Which is trying to reimplement [the method call postfix operator](https://docs.raku.org/routine/.&.html) to throw an exception for anything that is called. This does not work:

```
No such method 'newish' for invocant of type 'Nothing'
```

in block  at NYI.p6 line 13

And, in fact, the documentation says:

> Technically, not a real operator; it's syntax special-cased in the compiler.

Which most probably means it cannot be overridden. That also means that doing what I want implies interacting with the [metamodel](https://docs.raku.org/type/Metamodel::ClassHOW) to intercept the class resolution method. But I don't really see how this could be done. Most examples in Rakudo source, such as [this one](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/98e575de00db42101d4879e43fe740a34791c418/src/core/Routine.pm6), throw the exception when a concrete function is called, and, in fact, [the exception we see is thrown by the `dispatch` method at the `Mu` level](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/92eaa11a1f60713b174d78a35954d17382f76e51/src/core/Mu.pm6#L811-L821).

So would overriding `dispatch` be the right way to do this kind of thing? Or something else completely different?

Comment: Afaict you're already sorted 'cuz Lizmat has provided a good answer and you've accepted it and closed the doc issue. This comment is a heads up for you or future readers thinking of trying to get your `postfix:<.&>` approach to work. I can see what you're thinking but your attempt thus far is broken in multiple ways. Some are fixable but overall it can't work because it's incompatible with P6's grammar. That's why it's special cased. Aiui something like it may one day be possible if [007](https://github.com/masak/007) evolves to cover this case and gets merged back into a future P6.

Comment: (After [some discussion at the 007 project](https://github.com/masak/007/issues/294#issuecomment-392582497), perhaps a slang would be better than a macro as an approach to overriding the method call operator.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Feels to me you want `FALLBACK`:

https://docs.raku.org/language/typesystem#index-entry-FALLBACK_%28method%29

which would translate to:

```
class Nothing {
    method FALLBACK($name, |c) is hidden-from-backtrace {
        die X::NYI.new( feature => $name,
                        did-you-mean => "nothing",
                        workaround => "Implement it yourself" );
    }
}

my $a = Nothing.newish;
============================
newish not yet implemented. Sorry.
Did you mean: nothing?
Workaround: Implement it yourself
  in block <unit> at file line 10
```

Note that I also used the `is hidden-from-backtrace` trait to make sure the `FALLBACK` method is not mentioned in the backtrace.